# How can I use HTML tags in a Zend\Form placeholder attribute

Tags: zend-framework2

I use `Zend\Form` to generate my forms. I have a **textarea** where I want to display some default text. Currently, I have it like this:

```
$this->add(array(                                                        
    'type' => 'textarea',                                                
    'name' => 'dialog',
    'options' => array(                                                  
        'label' => 'Dialog',                                             
    ),
    'attributes' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Person1: Hello!<br />Person2: Hi!',                                               
    ),                                                                   
));
```

However, this results in `<br />` being escaped to `&lt;br /&gt;`.

Is there a way to embed HTML tags in the placeholder through `Zend\Form`?

Comment: Do you want to place default text in the textarea?  If so, I believe you can set an attribute on the form element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't and you shouldn't. Please see the [official specifications](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute):

> The **placeholder** attribute represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry when the control has no value. A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format. The attribute, if specified, **must have a value that contains no U+000A LINE FEED (LF) or U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) characters**.

If you absolutely have to mimic this behavior, do so via JavaScript.

Comment: i gave you a plus one, but i would avoid using javascript to hack it in.

Comment: He's been asking for a `placeholder`. A simple value like your suggestion would require the user to select all and overwrite/delete the content. That's not very user-friendly. I didn't suggest JS to be used, it's just his only choice to mimic the behavior ;)

Comment: I am wondering, how do you know that a `<br />` in the `placeholder` for `textarea` does mean the same as LF or CR? For me LF and CR are only the direct characters in source. Is it W3C convention?

Comment: @Aufziehvogel this is because a `<br/>` is simply a sequence of characters. To achieve a line-break inside a `textarea` you need a LF. And those are not allowed inside a `placeholder`.

Answer (score -1):

for reference, in ZF1 you could create an element with default text in a textarea:

```
    $this->createElement(
        'textarea',
        'content', 
        array(
            'label' => 'Address', 
            'rows' => '3', 
            'value' => 'default value'
        )
    );
```

For ZF2, I recommend taking a look at the following documentation:

[textarea docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.1/classes/Zend.Form.Element.Textarea.html)

the library component you are using with for elements is,

```
class Element implements
    ElementAttributeRemovalInterface,
    ElementInterface,
    InitializableInterface
```

which is found at \Zend\Form\Element in the library.  you can see in the class that there are several methods for customizing your form elements which includes ::setValue() that you can use to set a value on a form element.

I believe this is was you are looking for, i.e. you don't need to use html tags in the placeholder attribute if what you are trying to do is simply have default text.

Comment: No, unfortunately it was not default text, but really a code example with newlines which vanishes, when you enter your own text.